# Python, multithreading too slow, multiprocess

Tags: python, multithreading, pool, multiprocess

I'm a multiprocessing newbie,

I know something about threading but I need to increase the speed of this calculation, hopefully with multiprocessing:

> **Example Description:** sends string to a thread, alters string + benchmark test,
>   send result back for printing.
>
> ```
> from threading import Thread
>
> class Alter(Thread):
>     def __init__(self, word):
>         Thread.__init__(self)
>         self.word = word
>         self.word2 = ''
>
>     def run(self):
>         # Alter string + test processing speed
>         for i in range(80000):
>             self.word2 = self.word2 + self.word
>
> # Send a string to be altered
> thread1 = Alter('foo')
> thread2 = Alter('bar')
> thread1.start()
> thread2.start()
>
> #wait for both to finish
> while thread1.is_alive() == True: pass
> while thread2.is_alive() == True: pass
>
>
> print(thread1.word2)
> print(thread2.word2)
> ```

This is currently takes about 6 seconds and I need it to go faster.
I have been looking into multiprocessing and cannot find something equivalent to the above code. I think what I am after is **pooling** but examples I have found have been hard to understand. I would like to take advantage of all cores (8 cores) `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` but I really just have scraps of useful information on multiprocessing and not enough to duplicate the above code. If anyone can point me in the right direction or better yet, provide an example that would be greatly appreciated. Python 3 please

Comment: don't busy-wait for thread to complete. use Thread.join()!

Comment: why not? I have done this in most of my coding and if you can provide a good reason, i will change it all :)

Comment: well it's at least as good as busy-waiting and probably makes it passively wait until the thread is terminated without eating the cpu (although i can't find it in the docs i'd wager cpython doesn't busy-wait in it's Thread.join()).

Comment: **this probably depends on platform anyway.

Comment: ok that makes sense, I think I'll use this join() moving forward

Comment: @Rhys: Busy-waiting like that will hold the GIL, and prevent your worker threads from running. Also, if you don't have enough CPUs, then a CPU that could be in your worker thread doing useful work, handling an OS interrupt, or dealing with some other process is instead generating heat.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just replace `threading` with `multiprocessing` and `Thread` with `Process`. Threads in Pyton are (almost) never used to gain performance because of the big bad GIL! I explained it in an another [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8623652/1107807) with some links to documentation and a [great talk about threading in python.](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2010-understanding-the-python-gil-82-3273690)

But the [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing) module is intentionally very similar to the threading module. You can almost use it as an drop-in replacement!

The multiprocessing module doesn't AFAIK offer a functionality to enforce the use of a specific amount of cores. It relies on the OS-implementation. You could use the Pool object and limit the worker-onjects to the core-count. Or you could look for an other MPI library like pypar. Under Linux you could use a pipe under the shell to start multiple instances on different cores

Comment: A good read on how Python handles multiprocessing vs threading on multicore is [here](http://www.martinkral.sk/blog/2011/03/python-multicore-vs-threading-example/)

Comment: @Don, Yes! it seems to work. I must just check how much faster its running. one thing though, the code above does not specify number of cores used ... would this be easy to include?

Comment: Hi, @Don, what you mean by **big bad GIL**? I'm a python newbie.

Comment: @mrroy: GIL = global interpreter lock; basically you have "real" threads (hardware/OS supported) bur you don't gain performance, but may even loose some. threading in cpython (2.x) is meant for concurrent I/O operations.