# How do I stop one piece of code to run another in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

For example, let's say I have a `function_1` and `function_2`. Would I be able to run `function_1`, stop mid-way, wait for `function_2` to be done, and then run the rest of `function_1` ?

Comment: What event would cause you to stop mid-way?  You could just put a call to `function_2` halfway through `function_1`'s code.

Comment: @DanielWalker At least when I tried it, the print statement in `function_1` ran, then `function_2`, then the second `function_1` print statement, but then only after that the `time.sleep(5)` inside `function_2` ran.

Comment: What do you mean by "stop midway"? Do you mean that ``function_1`` itself suspends at a specific point? Do you mean that some third party pauses ``function_1`` (at a given time, instruction, ...?)? Does ``function_1`` know about ``function_2``? Why doesn't ``function_1`` *call* ``function_2`` at the appropriate point?

Comment: Would you mind editing your post and showing us at least some pseudo-code for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a python thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623573/what-is-a-python-thread)

Comment: This is what ***`threading`*** is for. See also [Pausing a thread using threading class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262346/pausing-a-thread-using-threading-class)

Answer (score 2):

Are both functions run under the same process, on the same thread? (if you don't know what this means, they probably are)

If so, there isn't really a good way to do this directly. My advice would be to refactor your code somehow so this isn't necessary, possibly by breaking up functions into smaller functions (so you could run a small function that does the first part of function 1, then run function 2, then run a small function that does the second part of function 1)

Another way would be to call function 2 from within function 1, which would transfer control to function 2 until function 2 returns.

Which one of these is the better choice will depend on the nature of your problem.

EDIT: these of course are not the *only* ways to do this, (the asker *could* run the functions on seperate threads, and do explicit synchronization) but these are two fairly simple ways to do what they want.

Answer (score 1):

i thing this might help but if you a clear answer please provide an example or an idea of what you trying to make

```
def func1():
print("func1")

def  func2():
    print("part1")
    func1()
    print("part2")

func2()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the functions are not too complex and arent heavily reliant on efficiency  than a crude solution would be to use pythons time module and use `time.sleep` wherever  you need a function to stall..

You could also try calls to `function_2` within `function_1` these ideas are often used in the programming concept of **recursion**
So my idea would be

```
def function_1():
#function1 code
function_2()
#the rest of function1's code

def function_2():
#function_2's code
```

This should follow the flow you want

hope this helps!