# How can I get Thread ID in Python 2.4.3?

Tags: python, multithreading, process, pid

I have a program and I start 3 threads separately. I am using version 2.4.3.

`thread.get_ident()` is not available in this version of Python I guess. 
I use `threading.currentThread()` but it only returns me this:

`<_MainThread(MainThread, started)>`

In other versions (3.3.3) I get something like

`<_MainThread(MainThread, started 5420)>`

where `5420` represents the Thread ID. How can I get this ID in Python 2.4 Versions?

Comment: This Link may help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919897/how-to-find-a-thread-id-in-python]

Comment: This is what it returns `<Thread(Thread-1, started)>`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [2.4.3 `thread` docs](https://docs.python.org/release/2.4.3/lib/module-thread.html), `get_ident` is a method on `thread`:

> #### get_ident()
>
> Return the 'thread identifier' of the current thread. This is a nonzero integer. Its value has no direct meaning; it is intended as a magic cookie to be used e.g. to index a dictionary of thread-specific data. Thread identifiers may be recycled when a thread exits and another thread is created.