# print current thread in python 3

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-3.x

I have this script:

```
import threading, socket

for x in range(800)
    send().start()

class send(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.connect(("www.google.it", 80))
                s.send ("test")
                print ("Request sent!")
            except:
                pass
```

And at the place of "Request sent!" I would like to print something like: "Request sent! %s" % (the current number of the thread sending the request)

What's the fastest way to do it?

**--SOLVED--**

```
import threading, socket

for x in range(800)
    send(x+1).start()

class send(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.connect(("www.google.it", 80))
                s.send ("test")
                print ("Request sent! @", self.counter)
            except:
                pass
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find a thread id in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919897/how-to-find-a-thread-id-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass your counting number (`x`, in this case), as a variable in your send class. Keep in mind though that `x` will start at 0, not 1.

```
for x in range(800)
    send(x+1).start()

class send(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, count):
        self.count = count

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.connect(("www.google.it", 80))
                s.send ("test")
                print ("Request sent!"), self.count
            except:
                pass
```

Or, as Rob commented above in the other question, [`threading.current_thread()`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.current_thread) looks satisfactory.

Comment: thanks for the answer. It raises: [code]    raise RuntimeError("thread.__init__() not called")
RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called
[/code]

Comment: solved by adding "threading.Thread.__init__(self)" to __init__ function. thanks

Comment: but i still can't understand why send(x+1).start() has this +1

Comment: @allexj It's because `range(800)` starts with 0 not 1, so when we say "Request sent!" for the first time we're saying "this is the first one!" instead of "this is the zeroth one!"

Answer (score 4):

Just a side answer to how to get the thread ID of the current thread (might not respond directly to the question but help others):
In python 3.3+ you can do simply :

```py
import threading

threading.get_ident()
```

Read more : [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.get_ident)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use `setName` and `getName` to give names to your threads.

```
import threading, socket

for x in range(800)
    new_thread = send()
    new_thread.setName("thread number %d" % x)
    new_thread.start()

class send(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                s.connect(("www.google.it", 80))
                s.send ("test")
                print ("Request sent by %s!" % self.getName())
            except:
                pass
```

You can also add any other attributes to `send` that you need to keep track of your threads.