# Why two methods with same functionality available in threading module in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

For `threading.Thread`, there are two methods which seems to have same functionality :

- `is_alive` and `isAlive`

For `threading.Event`, there is below method :

- `is_set` and `isSet`

Similarly `threading` module , again these methods are available

- `currentThread`  and `current_thread`
- `active_count` and `activeCount`

So, question is, though it seems, both the methods have same functionality, **why there are two methods available?**

Also, **which one is preferable** ?

Comment: it's just backwards naming compatibility. Use the lowercase+underscore version from now on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919897/how-to-find-a-thread-id-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python, as a rule, uses [`lowercase` or `lowercase_with_underscores` for method and function names](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names). The `threading` module incorrectly used `mixedCase` for many of the names when first added to Python. They later added the `lowercase_with_underscores` names as aliases for style consistency with the rest of Python.

In general, use the `lowercase_with_underscores` names unless your code needs to run on Python 2.5 or earlier (the fixed names were added in 2.6). That said, [the docs note](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html):

> Note: Starting with Python 2.6, this module provides PEP 8 compliant aliases and properties to replace the camelCase names that were inspired by Java’s threading API. This updated API is compatible with that of the multiprocessing module. However, no schedule has been set for the deprecation of the camelCase names and they remain fully supported in both Python 2.x and 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of style. Before underscore style was officially accepted as Python's style there were libraries already using different style. So functions were renamed but due to compatibility issues old name versions had to be kept as well.

Anyway [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) suggests to use underscore style so I advice sticking with it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but its just aliases from different versions of Python i think and they have same function

The reason is to keep compatibility with olders version of Python