# Python logger PID different in top

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, logging, python-multithreading

I initialise my logger in `main.py` like so:

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(process)d - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

Then in each module at the top I have:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

When I use the logger in multiple threads, the process id shown is the same (the parent id), the thread ID is different if included. However, when I use the `top` commandline tool in linux, I see different PIDs for each thread.

How can I show the child PID when it uses the logger? I need to narrow down where an issue is occuring and I can't from just knowing the module name.

For example, when I have my main thread spawn another thread, top shows these two entries:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
 9686 jm354     20   0  528608  17584   9192 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.07 python                                                                                                          
 9690 jm354     20   0  528608  17584   9192 S   0.0   0.2   0:00.01 python
```

But the logs only shows the PID 9686, despite logger.info being used in different threads.

I'm using the multiprocessing Queue and threading.Thread modules

```
import logging
import threading
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

Comment: What you're seeing in `top` is probably the OS threads that python threads are mapped to. Can you show the output here?

Comment: @DroidX86 done :)

Comment: Does yours script use the multiprocessing module by any chance? Or maybe some library you're using is using the multiprocessing module?

Comment: multiprocessing queues are being used, and threading.Thread. I've added the exact imports.

Comment: Can you try printing the process tree? Check the `pstree` command. That might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9410056/1581400) they discuss a solution using `ctypes` and Linux-specific code. This is not portable but could do for debugging.