# print(threading.current_thread().getName()+ str (' is starting \n')) why is the getName() crossed out?

Tags: python, parallels

Hello this is my code but idk why is the getName() crossed out??? [picture][1]
btw i use python
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHWm2.png

```
import time

def functionOne() :
    print(threading.current_thread().getName()+ str (' is starting \n'))
    time.sleep(2)
    print(threading.current_thread().getName() + str (' is exiting \n'))
    return

def functionTwo():
    print(threading.current_thread().getName() + str (' is starting \n'))
    time.sleep(2)
    print(threading.currentthread().getName() + str (' is exiting \n'))
    return

def functionThree():
    print(threading.currentthread().getName() + str (' is starting \n'))
    time.sleep(2)
    print(threading.currentthread().getName() + str (' is exiting \n'))
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(name='functionOne',target=functionOne)
    t2 = threading.Thread(name='functionTwo',target=functionTwo)
    t3 = threading.Thread(name='functionThree',target=functionThree)

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
```

Comment: Why `currentthread` and `current_thread`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919897/how-to-obtain-a-thread-id-in-python

Answer (score 4):

`getName()` has [been recently deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.getName), according to the docs:

> Deprecated getter/setter API for name; use it directly as a property instead.

> Deprecated since version 3.10.

Thus I presume you are running Python 3.10, so use this instead:

```
threading.current_thread().name
```

Also note the comment - later code uses `currentthread()` without an underscore, so that needs to be corrected too.